# Exporting rules of a feature flag in launchdarkly

Tags: launchdarkly

I have a few feature flags with multiple rules. for eg -  [image]

I want to export the rules in a readable format (json, xml etc)

for eg -

```
{
  rule2: {
      contextKind: ..., 
      values: ["US", ...] 
  }
}
```

Is there a quick way to do it?